# How to change the Colors in rectbin plot in Gadfly?

Tags: plot, statistics, julia, gadfly

I am using Gadfly to plot a rectbin in Julia

```
ticks = [2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015]
plot(y=c[1:100],x=y[1:100], Guide.ylabel("Countries"), 
Guide.xlabel("Year"),Guide.title("GDP of Asian Countries from 2006-
2015"),Geom.rectbin,color=g,Guide.xticks(ticks=ticks))
```

How do I change the default colors?

Here's the graph that is being plotted:

[image]

Comment: After looking at the "gadfly" website I have a few questions. Is "R" a correct tag to have on this post ? Isn't this "Julia" related ?

Comment: @steveb - What are your questions?

Comment: Just whether the post is tagged correctly by using the R tag.  I see you removed the tag now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news and bad news:

Good news is you can use `Scale.continuous_color_scale_partial(f)` as an extra argument to `plot()`, where `f(v)` receives a value between 0 and 1 and returns a color

Bad news is another function like this is nowhere to be found but the [default one](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/scale.jl#L614) as of this writing.

You'll have to do your own. Maybe you can start with a [basic example](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/633#issuecomment-125998295) or try to aproximate values based off [matplotlib's colormaps](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/196f3446a3d5178c58144cee796fa8e8aa8d2917/lib/matplotlib/_cm_listed.py#L774).